# ffmpeg converting multiple audio formats to mp3

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I was wondering how can I convert multiple audio formats, i.e. wav, aac, m4a to mp3 at once with ffmpeg and php (not ffmpeg-php)?

So if this:

`ffmpeg -i son_origine.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3 son_final.mp3`

Converts wav to mp3, how can I add multiple extensions in there?

Comment: Why downvote? I don't see anything wrong with my question.

Comment: Why not change the command and run it again, or automate with a script?

Comment: I was under the impression that all the desired file extensions could be used on one line, but seems that it isn't the case. At least I haven't found anything nor got anything working by myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a find - exec command like this

```
find $DIR -type f \( -name "*.wav" -o -name "*.aac" -o -name "*.m4a" -o -name "*.mov" -o -name "*.wmv" \) -exec ffmpeg -i '{}' -ffmpeg options- '{}.mp3' \;
```